# how to place two numbers together in an equation

Tags: c

I want to make it so that I can place two numbers together as a single number in an equation. for example if I input the numbers 1, 0 and 5, I want the output to be 50. (10 * 5)

```
scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &a);
z = xy * a
```

edit:
here is actual code

```
case 'a':
case 'A':
    printf("\nEnter the first 2 colors");
    scanf("%s %s", color1, color2);
    printf("enter the third and fourth colors");
    scanf("%s %s", color3, color4);
    value = valueFromColor(color1)valueFromColor(color2) * valueFromColor(color3);
    printf("%d", value);
```

I need the first color and second color to form a single number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    char x[16], y[16], xy_s[32];
    int xy, a, z;
    scanf("%15s %15s %d", x, y, &a);
    sprintf(xy_s, "%s%s", x, y);
    sscanf(xy_s, "%d", &xy);
    z = xy * a;
    printf("%d\n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't put space in the `printf` call:

```
 z = (10*x+y)*a;
 printf("%d = %d%d * %d", z, x, y, a);
```

**EDIT:**

To handle the general case, where `y` has more than one digit use this:

```
no_of_digs = ceil(log(y)/log(10));
z = (pow(10, no_of_digs)*x+y)*a;
printf("%d = %d%d * %d", z, x, y, a);
```

Comment: well the output is supposed to be just 50, I just want to know how to make the equation (z = xy * a) work.

Comment: This is answered in my first line (pretty basic by the way).

Comment: I know is basic, I'm fairly new, but I think Im explaining myself wrong. That equation only works because the y is a 0, but if the y were to be 11, how can I make it so the output is 555 (111 * 5)?